# Android native runtime fails to load symbols even though they are actually found in the loaded .so files

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I have compiled ffmpeg v3.4 using NDK v15.2 and I'm creating a wrapper lib called ffmpeg-jni.

```
static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("avutil");
        System.loadLibrary("avcodec");
        System.loadLibrary("avformat");
        System.loadLibrary("swscale");
        System.loadLibrary("avfilter");
        System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg-jni"); // Exception here line#101
        loadedLibraries = true;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Below is the exception thrown when loading my wrapper library.

```
10-24 11:12:13.819 21499-21499/com.myeglu.android.canary.staging W/System.err: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "av_register_all" referenced by "/data/app/com.myeglu.android.canary.staging-2/lib/arm/libffmpeg-jni.so"...
```

But, to my surprise, this function is defined in libavformat.so, which loaded successfully; This is clear from the [nm tool output](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/71546823db69969af805caceb971e4b5)that the av_register_all() function is defined (T) in libavformat.so

Here is a link of all the pre-built libraries that are troubling to make peace at runtime. (There are a few other libraries as well apart from the ffmpeg libs)

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B20ExoMyOP_UeDhNdmwzc2tjR3M?usp=sharing

Somebody help me understand what I could be missing in this case. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It won't link the libraries if they're not in the correct folder in your project. For example: app/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a And your gradle script needs to reference them which you haven't shown here.

Comment: Libraries are tucked into the apk properly and there is only one variant armeabi as of now. At runtime, it is able to load them properly as well. Exception is coming after loading all other dependent libraries.

Comment: Your av-libs belong to armeabi-v7a, not armeabi. So, if you build **libffmpeg-jni.so** for  armeabi, this could cause a problem with loading the lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, you should either list explicitly all needed libraries in correct order, or let the system resolve the dependencies (if your platform is at least Lollipop).

Specifically, **libavcodec** requires **libswresample**.

But **ffmpeg-jni** seems to be not built correctly. Its **Dynamic** section only lists

```
0x00000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [libandroid.so]
0x00000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [libjnigraphics.so]
0x00000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [libavcodec.so]
0x00000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [liblog.so]
0x00000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [libc.so]
```

Also, the **.dynsym** table contains

```
 5: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND av_register_all
```

I would expect, instead,

```
 5: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND av_register_all@LIBAVFORMAT_57 (4)
```

Note that symbol type for **avcodec_find_decoder** and other references that come from **libavcodec.so** in your library is correct.

Could you have used `LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=true` for **libffmpeg-jni.so**?

**Update**: actually, cmake uses `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS` prepared by Android toolchain to pass `--no-undefined` to the linker; by overriding this variable you effectively allowed undefined symbols (and lost some other important flags that are tuned for Android). The bottom line is, overriding CMAKE standard variables is dangerous.

Comment: I have set libavcodec.so as dependent in my cmake script. This in turn depends on libavformat.so, libswscale.so, libavutil.so, libavcodec.so and libavfilter.so; 

During compile time, these files are all available using cmake external build and I could navigate to the appropriate header files from my IDE. They are also tucked into the APK and are made available at runtime for loading. But the link is not resolved properly when the libffmpeg-jni.so is being loaded.

Comment: I haven't set LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=true any where in my project config.

Comment: No, libavformat depends on libavcodec, not vice versa. Try to add dependency on  libavformat explicitly for libffmpeg-jni.so in your cmake script

Comment: Found it. I had to add all the dependent libraries as dependents for my jni wrapper. Libs are not packed transitively.

Comment: I still don't know how you achieved the `NOTYPE` references before. This could be a real issue with the NDK linker. Could you please share the *old wrong* script that produced **libffmpeg-jni.so** that failed to load at runtime.

Comment: I have created a gist of the earlier setup here. https://gist.github.com/Gopinathp/4fc523ec922117f2f3928eef2fb2e4fa

Comment: The mystery resolved: you override `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS` which was prepared by Android toolchain, and had `-Wl,--no-undefined` among other useful arguments.

Comment: Thanks for solving the puzzle. Newbie here on the NDK. Made it to the following and now its working : 

set (CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,--as-needed,-v")

Comment: if you want to pass `-v` to linker, you need a space before it, not `,`

Comment: Thanks. But, What does -Wl,--as-needed mean, which is separated by comma.

Comment: When we link for Android, we use **clang** or (now deprecated) **gcc** to invoke the linker. Some flags, like `-v`, are be passed directly; other linker flags, like `--as-needed `, are not recognized by **clang**, and we need `-Wl,` prefix to help it.

Comment: `--as-needed` tells the linker only to write the names of needed external shared libs in the ELF header. In your case, it may remove **libm.so** from the list saved in **libffmpeg-jni.so**.